# How to run windows 8 made vb application on windows 7?

Tags: basic

I want to run an app that I made in Visual Studio on a Windows 7 computer
I thought it would run, but it did not.
Please tell me how to run this Windows 8 made application on a Windows 7 computer!

-Thnx
@AhmadTheCoder

Answer (score 1):

By a Windows 8 App, I am assuming you mean a Metro/Modern app? If you are, then you you can use ModernMix, but you need to pay, and if it is going out into the public, everybody is going to need to buy that to run your app. If you need to run your apps on Windows 7 and such, you should rewrite your application into a Windows Forms application. You do not get the fullscreen experience like you do with the modern apps, but it is the only way to get it compatible.